# Installing Kubernetes 1.25 Offline

Tags: kubernetes

We are trying to setup a basic kubernetes (v1.25) cluster in a set of VMs (centos 7) which are offline (internet blocked). We have downloaded the images of the kubernetes server components (i.e. apiserver, controller, etcd, kube-proxy, scheduler, coredns etc.) in another server through docker pull where the internet is active, saed those images as tar, transferred them into the offline server, imported into the containerd image repository (`ctr -n=k8s.io image import kube-apiserver-v1.25.0.tar`). However, if we try to pull the images (`kubeadm config images pull`) or do the `kubeadm init` to start the master node, we are getting error as it is trying to connect to `registry.k8s.io` domain and subsequently to domain `storage.googleapis.com` domain.
We took a temporarily special approval to get connectivity with the above 2 domains to run the kubeadm init command to create the kubernetes containers.
Could you please provide a solution so that the initial HEAD call also goes to the local image registry rather than going to the online registry?
Eventhough we took permission for connectivity with the kubernetes specific domains, while we are trying to install CALICO as network plugin, we are facing similar issues as it has its own domains to connect. And is a similar way, it would happen for any image from an online public registry. So effectively we need a solution to this.

Below is the error which we got while running kubeadm init before we got the kubernetes domains connected to our server.

```
$ kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.184.48.0/24 --kubernetes-version=1.25.0 --apiserver-advertiseddress=$(hostname -i)
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.25.0
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0: output: E0908 08:30:08.405405   19080 remote_image.go:238] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-apiserver/manifests/v1.25.0\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:51094->[::1]:53: read: connection refused" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0"
time="2022-09-08T08:30:08Z" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-apiserver/manifests/v1.25.0\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:51094->[::1]:53: read: connection refused"
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0: output: E0908 08:30:08.473579   19110 remote_image.go:238] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-controller-manager/manifests/v1.25.0\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:54055->[::1]:53: read: connection refused" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0"
time="2022-09-08T08:30:08Z" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-controller-manager/manifests/v1.25.0\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:54055->[::1]:53: read: connection refused"
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0: output: E0908 08:30:08.540054   19140 remote_image.go:238] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-scheduler/manifests/v1.25.0\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:60665->[::1]:53: read: connection refused" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0"
time="2022-09-08T08:30:08Z" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-scheduler/manifests/v1.25.0\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:60665->[::1]:53: read: connection refused"
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0: output: E0908 08:30:08.604658   19172 remote_image.go:238] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-proxy/manifests/v1.25.0\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:57387->[::1]:53: read: connection refused" image="registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0"
time="2022-09-08T08:30:08Z" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy:v1.25.0\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/kube-proxy/manifests/v1.25.0\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:57387->[::1]:53: read: connection refused"
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8: output: E0908 08:30:08.664003   19202 remote_image.go:238] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/pause/manifests/3.8\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:33765->[::1]:53: read: connection refused" image="registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8"
time="2022-09-08T08:30:08Z" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.8\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/pause/manifests/3.8\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:33765->[::1]:53: read: connection refused"
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0: output: E0908 08:30:08.724547   19233 remote_image.go:238] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/etcd/manifests/3.5.4-0\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:50537->[::1]:53: read: connection refused" image="registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0"
time="2022-09-08T08:30:08Z" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/etcd/manifests/3.5.4-0\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:50537->[::1]:53: read: connection refused"
, error: exit status 1
        [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3: output: E0908 08:30:08.783023   19264 remote_image.go:238] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/coredns/coredns/manifests/v1.9.3\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:33298->[::1]:53: read: connection refused" image="registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3"
time="2022-09-08T08:30:08Z" level=fatal msg="pulling image: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns:v1.9.3\": failed to do request: Head \"https://registry.k8s.io/v2/coredns/coredns/manifests/v1.9.3\": dial tcp: lookup registry.k8s.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:33298->[::1]:53: read: connection refused"
, error: exit status 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Comment: Are you using `containerd` as a CRI?
Did you download your images from the official registry (registry.k8s.io)?

Comment: Yes, I am using containerd as CRI. I downloaded the images from official registry and imported into my repo server. I try the kubeadm commands from the master node, expecting it to pull the images from my repo server.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here, the easiest one is to tag the images that you downloaded with **registry.k8s.io** in each node (depending on your setup, control-plane/worker):

```
ctr --namespace=k8s.io image tag <yourimage> registry.k8s.io/<yourimage>
```

Like

```
ctr --namespace=k8s.io image tag etcd:3.5.4-0 registry.k8s.io/etcd:3.5.4-0
```

If you retag all images that you need you can install it offline without issues.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the same, however, ended up with the same error though. Let me explain the setup. 
I have one VM operating as my repo server, another VM is acting as my master node. 
In repo VM, I downloaded the images for kubernetes server components, installed containerd, imported all the images into containerd with namespace k8s.io. I can see the images with "ctr -n k8s.io images ls". 
However, when I try "kubeadm config images pull", it gives me same error irrespective of I do/do not tag the images in the repo VM with or without "registry.k8s.io".

Comment: Debanjan, you have to pull all images needed manually to each node, retaging in the repo is not to make pull the images locally (kubernetes will go to inet). So if you have a master node and few workers you need to pull all images that you need in each of them and retag to make it work.